# How to restore current directories after reopening?

Tags: macos, shell

I use zsh (the default shell for macOS) and I have number of tabs opened, with different name.

The problem is that on restart it reopens tabs, but loses current directories.
Is there a way to make the shell to rostore directories after restart?

Comment: Are you referring to tabs in `zsh` (with some plugin maybe)? Or to tabs in your terminal emulator? What is your terminal emulator then? Is it *Terminal*, the default terminal emulator for macOS?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I use default. Updated question. Thanks.

Comment: `zsh` is no terminal emulator, but a shell. You seem to mix up terminology here. [Explanation of the differences.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con)

Comment: thanks. fixed the text